# How would I make a grid layout occupy 1/2 of a screen?

Tags: android, android-layout

My current thinking is to use a horizontal LinearLayout with 1/2 as the Weightsum but that does not make the Linearlayout occupy 1/2 of the screen (which would have allowed me to place a Gridlayout on top).

How would I make the Gridlayout occupy the upper 1/2 of the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `weightSum` attribute on the parent `LinearLayout`.

In the following example, the weight of the `GridLayout` will be `1` out of a total `2` (so 1 half).

```xml
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```